# The same identifier is considered by the C# compiler as a different type in the same function

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compiler-errors

I have and extension method which takes three parameters of identical type name.

The problem is that the C# compiler resolves the first and second argument as type ServerModels.Action, but the third parameter is resolved as System.Action.

How is it possible that exactly the same identifier is considered as a different type?

[image]

Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013 
Version 12.0.40629.00 Update 5 
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5

Comment: Actions <-> Action

Comment: They *aren't* the same name.  Action**s** vs Action

Comment: I am seeing to ServerModels.Action and one System.Action, because your code looks like `Actions action1, Actions action2 Action action3` action three is being passed as a different object type. I suspect you just need to change action3 type to `Actions` rather than `Action`

Answer (score 2):

The third one is resolving as `System.Action` as the other parameters are `ServerModels.Actions` (note the "s")

Answer (score 1):

I am seeing to `ServerModels.Action` and one `System.Action`, because your code looks like `Actions action1, Actions action2 Action action3` action three is being passed as a different object type. I suspect you just need to change action3 type to `Actions` rather than `Action`